# MySql Select data from SubQuery when master query has groupby clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySql db.

```
1) networks (NetworkId, NetworkType) 
2) users (Id, NetworkId, IpAddress)
```

Using [`NetworkId` and `IpAddress`] defines unique users.

Now, I want to use `group by` clause on NetworkType and at the same time want to list count of all users as like below:

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(distinct IpAddress) FROM users
        WHERE NetworkId in nr.NetworkId ) as UsersCount
FROM networks as nr
GROUP BY NetworkType;
```

But due to any reason I always gets zero users.

When I run following queries

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCATE(nr.NetworkId)
FROM networks as nr
GROUP BY NetworkType;
```

Then I am getting valid values with ',' separated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I use subqueries in select column part specially with grouped data ?

Comment: In any case, I want to put where condition on "nr.NetworkId" because network table has lot more complexity with its grouped data.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0, You changed target table on which group by clause applied, I have more than 10 columns attached with networks and I can't do groupby on users table instead of networks.

Comment: Now you tell me.   You just have to change the query around.  But I guess that's why you came on here.  :)    I'll go adjust the fiddle here in a minute.

Comment: grouped by nr.network id

Comment: actuually use this version, its better ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15e34/17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated per your new information about what you needed with the group by.

How about an upvote for my efforts at least.

[Latest SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15e34/17)

```sql
select
    mysub.count, 
    nr.`networkid`
from 
    `networks` as nr,

(select 
    count(`ipaddress`) as count,
    `networkid`
from 
    `users`
where 
    `networkid`
in (
    select 
        `networkid`
    from 
        `networks`
   )
group by 
    `networkid`) as mysub
    where nr.`networkid` = mysub.`networkid`
    group by nr.`networkid`
```

Comment: You changed target table on which group by clause applied, I have more than 10 columns attached with networks and I can't do groupby on users table instead of networks.

Comment: Fixed , see new fiddle link @RajdipPatel

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
select n.networktype, count(distinct u.ipaddress)
from networks n
    join users u on n.networkid = u.networkid
group by n.networktype
```

Comment: A brave effort - making sense of that gibberish!!

Comment: @Strawberry Oh sure, what about my efforts. ;P

Comment: @notoriouspet0 too little too late ;-)

Comment: @sgeddes Do you think since you have 35k rep you could leave the low hanging fruit for us newbies and maybe try to answer some harder questions?